# Asp.net MVC with Jaydata

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jaydata

How does asp.net mvc fit with Jaydata? Being that Jaydata is a javascript based query language than asp.net mvc and jaydata are not used together? i.e. with controllers and so on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 4 with the webAPI can mimic the data output like OData
http://jaydata.org/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-odata-based-ajax-application
with webapi you have far more control over how the data is output .

The problem is that some of the advanced querying has been put on hold while dev is ongoing ... the nightly builds still dont have it in quite yet.

start here: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api
 and it might work for what you need right away

Comment: Im wanting to integrate it into a "SPA" application. Ive already got a mature odata service, dont know for sure what benefits would get from investing into the webAPI. But thats not the problem right now its how to deal with the data at the client side that is what im tearing my hair out with. Finding the right tool.

Comment: On the client side then asp.net mvc would be a stable base to provide mostly static content any JavaScript mvc or mvvm library knockout backbone knockback etc.  and the HTML that goes along with it or am I missing what you are trying to do